# Bootstrap 5 on Laravel 8 , bootstrap js is not working(custom js is working)

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-5

i'm trying to install bootstrap 5 on laravel 8.

I installed bootstrap 5, jquery and popper.js, after that (i was using the cdn version) dropdown menu and toggle button is not working anymore, but my script is working.

That's how i did installation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKqJDWE0Wbo&ab_channel=NelisysDeveloper    .

If i'm right it's missing something about popper.js because bootstrap use it or it's some conflict between js library.

That's some file hope they could help.

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
        "fibers": "^5.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.8",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2"
    }
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
mix.js('resources/js/app.js','public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

bootstrap.js

```
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By migrating from Bootstrap 4 to 5, you have updated Popper from v1 to v2. The package has changed it's name and is now a scoped package. You can follow the migration guide of Popper [here](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/migration-guide/).
So you have to replace `popper.js` by `@popperjs/core` in `bootstrap.js`.

Also, Bootstrap 5 no longer require JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the bootstrap's official documentation. There are many updates.

For the current one: the 'data-toggle' attribute has been changed to 'data-bs-toggle'.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me also when I use popper with bootstrap on a non Laravel project.
after adding popper when I click on dropdown of navbar it gives me JS error related to popper.

The solution I found was that, to use only bootstrap.bundle.js instead of using bootstrap.js and popper.js separately.

for Example

//Comment these two:

```
<!--<script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
```

//Use this one:

```
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Read the first point in overview of below page for more information:
[getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/)